# Problems with references and master documents

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, cross-reference

I have a `Master Document` with chapter `subdocuments`. The `subdocuments` contain references using the `Citations and Bibliography` tool that Word comes with.

When working on the `subdocuments` I added many citations and they seem to be working well. I can insert an automated `Bibliography` section and then use `Update Citations and Bibliography` when I need the list to reflect new citations on the same `subdocument`.

The problem comes now that I am trying to merge the `subdocuments` with the master. I use the normal method to `Unlink` the files and have their contents on the `Master Document`, and the references are copied with the rest of the text, but when I press `Update Citations and Bibliography`, all the citations turn into Invalid source specified and they disappear from the `Bibliography` section.

I have tried to go to `Manage Sources` from within the `subdocument` and copy all the sources there to the `Master List`. They now appear in the `Master List` even when I am in the `Master Document`, but they still don't work properly.

Do you have any idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out.

1. For each `subdocument`, I went to `Manage Sources` and copied all
   the references on the Current List of that document (on the right
   column) to the `Master List`.
2. Closed and saved all documents.
3. Used `unlink` to merge the documents as normal.
4. On the `Master Document`, I went to `Manage Sources` and copied all the references
   on the `Master List` to the `Current List`. This leaves everything
   on the `Master List`, from any document with references created in
   Word into the `Current List` of the file. This fixes the problem
   that showed `Invalid source specified` when citations were inserted
   in line, but now the `Bibliography` section will have many unused
   references on it.
5. I selected all the references in the `Current List` and pressed delete on the `Source Manager`. This only deletes the sources that are not used in the document and both the in line citations and the `Bibliography` section work as intended.

Hope it helps someone in the future!